# 2 pipes writing to STDIN of the same child process

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, fork, child-process

I'm trying to write the stdout of 2 child processes into the stdin of a 3rd child process and am having trouble getting the second process to write into the process concurrently. Here process 3 is where the issue is. The keyboard input stdin does not work concurrently with the stdin coming from process 2.

```
void read_keyboard() {
while (!std::cin.eof()) {
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    } 
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::vector<pid_t> k;
    pid_t child_pid;
    int p1 [2];
    pipe(p1);

    //Fork that starts process 1 and pipes stdout to process 2
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0){

        close(p1[0]);
        dup2(p1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(p1[1]);
        //Start process 1. Process 1 runs continuously outputting to stdout.
    }

    //Fork that starts Process 2. Gets stdin from process 1 pipe and pipes stdout to process 3.
    int p2 [2];
    pipe(p2);
    int p3 [2];
    pipe(p3);
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0){

        dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p1[0]);

        dup2(p2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);

        //Start Process 2. This takes input from process 1 as stdin and outputs to process 3 as stdout.
    }

    //Fork that starts Process 3 and takes stdin from process 2 and read_keyboard(function that reads input until EOF)
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {

        dup2(p3[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(p3[1]);
        close(p3[0]);

        close(p2[1]);
        dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(p2[0]);

        //Start process 3. Reads stdin from process 2 to run, can also take stdin from keyboard. Outputs straight to the terminal.
    }

    //Fork that starts read_keyboard and pipes stdout to process 3
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0) {

        dup2(p3[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(p3[0]);
        close(p3[1]);

        read_keyboard();
    }

    dup2(p3[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(p3[0]);
    close(p3[1]);

    int status;
    wait(&status);
    //kill all the processes

}
```

The issue I'm having is everything works until you try to read from keyboard. The input just hangs until process 3 exits and then it tried to write to process 3. Can a child process handle 2 pipes both writing to its stdin? This conceptually makes sense to me but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `stdin` can only be connected to one pipe at a time. When you do `dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO)` then `stdin` is no longer connected to `p3[0]`. You need both writing processes to use the same pipe as their `stdout`.

Comment: If you redirect `stdin` to a pipe, `read_keyboard()` will read from the pipe, not from the keyboard.

Comment: If you want to read from the keyboard even though standard input is redirected, you need to open `/dev/tty`.

Comment: read_keyboard is just a function that reads whatever it typed into terminal until it see's EOF. It's not explicitly for the keyboard. But I didn't know I could not connect 2 pipes to stdin. When you say redirect stdin to a pipe, do you mean i can replace `dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO);` with something like `dup2(p2[0], p3[1]);`?

Comment: `read_keyboard()` is reading from `cin`, which reads from `STDIN_FILENO`. If you redirect stdin, that affects `cin`.

Comment: I mean you should just create one pipe. Both child 1 and child 2 dup the same pipe to `STDOUT_FILENO`, and child 3 dups it to `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: Wow, that solved my issue. I didn't realize you could use pipes like that. I was thinking 1 process, 1 data type, 1 pipe. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just to clarify, you weren’t ever interested in actually reading from the keyboard (and a pipe), right?